# simulating mouse click to download file from IE browser

Tags: excel, vba

Dashboard sample:

[image: Dashboard sample]

I'm trying to simulate a mouse click on a form on a browser to download report.
I got stuck immediately when targeting the download link/image.
I also realize the form is using a post method to retrieve the file, so I'm not sure if just simulating a mouseclick on the link/image is sufficient.

```
Sub TestDownload()
    Dim elements As Object, element As Object, count As Long
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://something.com/Dashboard"
    
    ' Wait while IE loading...
        Do While IE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
        
    count = 0
    Set elements = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    
    For Each element In elements
        If element.className = "ExportCurrentExtInt" Then
                   element.Click
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

```html
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="/NSPortal/Dashboards/CEPDashboard">
    <input type="hidden" name="ReportDate" id="ReportDate" value="4/1/2020" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Domain" id="Domain" value="" />
    **<input type="hidden" name="SubmitButton" id="SubmitButton" value="jqGridExportToExcel"> *--> the value appears when i click on the link to initiate the download*
    <input type="hidden" name="ExportTarget" id="ExportTarget" value="ExportCurrentExtInt">**
    <input type="hidden" name="ExportFilterField" id="ExportFilterField" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ExportFilterValue" id="ExportFilterValue" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="OpenTab" id="OpenTab" value=""/>
    <table id='tableDateSelection' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='border-color: #F5F5F5'>

</select>

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="RoundedPanelCenterLeft"></td>
                                    <td><a id="ExportCurrentExtInt">Export Current EXT-INT Interfaces &nbsp;<img style="vertical-align:top" alt="Export current EXT-INT Interfaces to Excel" src="/NSPortal/Content/Images/excel.gif" border="0"/></a></td>
                                    <td class="RoundedPanelCenterRight"></td>
                                </tr>

</form>
```

I tried to use Element ID but it's throwing me an error.

```
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

objIE.document.getElementById("ExportTarget").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: I notice you are looking for the link in your for loop with `If element.className = "ExportCurrentExtInt" Then...` but the link doesn't have a class name declared, I also noticed `"ExportCurrentExtInt"` is the `ID` element of the link. Perhaps this is causing your issue?

Comment: Thanks Samuel. 
i tried changing it by using just the ID in the form but that throws me an error.


` Wait while IE loading...
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

objIE.document.getElementById("ExportTarget").Click

End Sub`